# ASP.NET webforms wildcard route

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm using asp.net routing in a webforms app.

I would like to achieve the following url format:

http://[domain]/{parent-category}/{sub-category}/{sub-category}

where the right most category is available as a route value.

Currently I have achieved this with the following route:

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "category-browse",
            "{*category}",
            "~/category.aspx"
        );
```

This will pass all of the categories i.e. "trainers/running/nike-running-trainers" so I can grab the last one with a bit of string manipulation.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you need the ability to be flexible with 'optional' values - so that if user doesn't supply {sub-category} then you display all sub-categories - then your technique is pretty good.  Simply use String.split to separate your parameters

Comment: That's exactly what we are doing currently. I think this is the best we can do since the wildcard parameter needs to be the rightmost part of the route.

Comment: Did you find any better options?  I'm investigating this myself and am curious what method you ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can have an arbitrary number of sub-category parameters. If that's the case, the approach you're doing is the right one. ASP.NET Routing doesn't support having a catch-all parameter in the middle of the URL. It must be at the end. So what you described is the only way to do it short of writing your own custom RouteBase implementation.